# Converting a character string into a date in R

Tags: r, date

The data I'm trying to convert is supposed to be a date, however it is formatted as mmddyyyy with no separation by dashes or slashes. In order to work with dates in R, I would like to have this formatted as mm-dd-yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy.

I think I might need to use `grep()`, but I'm not sure how to use it to reformat all of the dates that are in the mmddyyyy format.

Comment: `as.Date("12252015", format="%m%d%Y")`

Answer (score 9):

**Updated**: Improved with [@Richard Scriven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3063910/richard-scriven)'s `colClasses` and simpler `as.Date()` suggestions

Here are two similar methods that worked for me, going from a csv containing `mmddyyyy` format date, to getting it recognized by R as a date object.

Starting first with a simple file tv.csv:

```
Series,FirstAir
Quantico,09272015
Muppets,09222015
```

### Method 1: All as string

Once within R,

```
> t = read.csv('tv.csv', colClasses = 'character')
```

- imports `tv.csv` as a data frame named `t`
- `colClasses = 'character')` option causes all the data to be considered the `character` data type (instead of being `Factor`, `int` types)

Examine its initial structure:

```
> str(t)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Series  : chr  "Quantico" "Muppets"
 $ FirstAir: chr  "09272015" "09222015"
```

- R has imported all as strings of characters, indicated here as type `chr`

The `chr` or string of characters are then easily converted into a date:

```
> t$FirstAir = as.Date(t$FirstAir, "%m%d%Y")
```

- `as.Date()` performs string to date conversion
- `%m%d%Y` specifies how to interpret the input in `t$FirstAir`. These format codes, at least on Linux, can be found with running `$ man date` which brings up the manual on the `date` program, where there is a list of formatting codes. For example it says `%m     month (01..12)`

### Method 2: Import then fix only the date

If for some reason you don't want a blanket import conversion to all characters, for example a file with many variables and wish to leave R's auto type recognition in use but merely "fix" the one date variable, follow this method.

Once within R,

```
> t = read.csv('tv.csv')
```

- imports `tv.csv` as a data frame named `t`

Examine its initial structure:

```
> str(t)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Series  : Factor w/ 2 levels "Muppets","Quantico": 2 1
 $ FirstAir: int  9272015 9222015
>
```

- R tries its best to guess the variable type per variable
- As you can see an immediate problem is, for `FirstAir` variable R has imported `09272015` as `int` meaning integer, and dropped off the leading zero padding , the 0 in 09 is important later for date conversion yet R has imported it without. So we need to fix this.

This can be done in a single command but for clarity I have broken this into two steps. First,

```
> t$FirstAir = sprintf("%08d", t$FirstAir)
```

- `sprintf` is a formatting function
- `0` means pad with zeroes
- `8` means ensure 8 characters, because mmddyyyy is total 8 characters
- `d` is used when the input is a number, which currently it is, recall `str()` output claimed the `t$FirstAir` is an `int` meaning integer
- `t$FirstAir` is the variable we are both setting and using as input

Check the result:

```
> str(t$FirstAir)
 chr [1:2] "09272015" "09222015"
```

- it successfully converted from an `int` to a `chr` type, for example `9272015` became `"09272015"`

Now it is a string or `chr` type we can then convert, same as method 1.

```
> t$FirstAir = as.Date(strptime(t$FirstAir, "%m%d%Y"))
```

### Result

We do a final check:

```
> str(t$FirstAir)
 Date[1:2], format: "2015-09-27" "2015-09-22"
```

In both cases, what were original values in a text file are have now been successfully converted into R date objects.

Comment: You could also use `t <- read.csv("tv.csv", colClasses = "character")`.  This sets all columns to character so you won't lose the leading zeroes. Then set the date with `t$FirstAir <- as.Date(t$FirstAir, "%m%d%Y")`

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at `lubridate` `mdy` function

```
require(lubridate)
a <- "10281994"
mdy(a)
```

gives you

```
[1] "1994-10-28 UTC"
```

of class `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"` so a datetime in R. (thanks Joshua Ulrich for the correction)

You could use `as.Date(mdy(a))` = `1994-10-28` to get a Object of class `Date`.

There are mutations like `ymd` and `dmy` within `lubridate` as well.

Comment: `Date` classed objects are dates in R. `POSIXct` objects are datetimes, not dates.