# Format Date/Time in R to match custom "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM" format from excel

Tags: r, date, time, utc, posixct

I have imported an excel file into R that has a Date and Time column that I need help formatting to match `m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM`, similar to a custom date function in excel. The Date column is currently formatted as `%Y-%M%-%D` and is in POSIXct format when imported to R. The Time column looks similar to the following:

```
File$Time <- c("0:00", "0:30", "1:00", "1:30", "13:30")
```

I need help converting these intervals to times as such 0:00 would be 12:00 AM and 13:30 would be 1:30 PM etc. Then I need to add 4 to each time to get it into UTC time. Once that has been done I need a single column that matches the `m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM` format with the date and time from the excel file.

Thanks for any tips or help in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a character string into a date in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32854538/converting-a-character-string-into-a-date-in-r)

Comment: Something like `x = as.POSIXct(paste(date_col, time_col), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")` and then `format(x, some_other_format)`. To determine the right format strings, there's a listing in `?strptime`.

Comment: Or, if the problem is merging date and time into date.time: combine date and time into datetime: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609252/r-tick-data-merging-date-and-time-into-a-single-object