# Convert dd/mm/yyyy H to date format

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have the following column in R

```
dteday = c("01/01/2011 0", "01/01/2011 1" , "01/01/2011 2", "01/01/2011 19")
df = data.frame(dteday)
```

```
        dteday
1  01/01/2011 0
2  01/01/2011 1
3  01/01/2011 2
4  01/01/2011 19
```

I want the column to be converted into a proper %d/%m/%Y H:M format
The string on the left is in %d/%m/%Y format while the integer on the right is the hour. The integer on the right represents the hour / time. This is my desired output

```
        dteday
1  01/01/2011 00:00
2  01/01/2011 01:00
3  01/01/2011 02:00
4  01/01/2011 19:00
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a character string into a date in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32854538/converting-a-character-string-into-a-date-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*That* specificly-formatted output can be achieved by combining `strftime` and `as.POSIXct`, but it will still be a character string

```
df$dteday = strftime(as.POSIXct(df$dteday, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H"), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
#             dteday
# 1 01/01/2011 00:00
# 2 01/01/2011 01:00
# 3 01/01/2011 02:00
# 4 01/01/2011 19:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Without converting to date you *could* do:

```
sapply(
  strsplit(dteday, ' '), 
  function(x) sprintf('%s %02d:00', x[1], as.integer(x[2])))
)

# [1] "01/01/2011 00:00" "01/01/2011 01:00" "01/01/2011 02:00" "01/01/2011 19:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lubridate`'s `dmy_h` to convert string to POSIXct.

```
df$dteday <- lubridate::dmy_h(df$dteday)
df$dteday

#[1] "2011-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" "2011-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" 
#    "2011-01-01 02:00:00 UTC" "2011-01-01 19:00:00 UTC"
```

Then use `format` to get data in format of your choice.

```
format(df$dteday, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
#[1] "01/01/2011 00:00" "01/01/2011 01:00" "01/01/2011 02:00" "01/01/2011 19:00"
```